# How to Handle colon(:) in Attribute in JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

```
<Item lims:fid="1174566" lims:id="1174566"><Text>Combat 18 (C18)</Text></Item></List><HistoricalNote><HistoricalNoteSubItem lims:inforce-start-date="2018-05-23" lims:fid="694437" lims:id="694437">
```

i want to get value of Attribute `lims:id="1174566` but it did not read the value

```
@XmlAttribute(name="lims:id")
private String id="";
```

please help me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part before the colon usually defines a namespace in xml. You need to define it in your root tag and the specify it in your Tag.

```
<Item xmlns:lims="http://your.domain.com/xml/lims" lims:fid="1174566" lims:id="1174566">
    <Text>Combat 18 (C18)</Text>
</Item>
```

JAXB:

```
@XmlAttribute(name="id", namespace="http://your.domain.com/xml/lims")
private String id="";
```